How can I go from the output data of the CIFAR10 function of the torchvision package, datasets to data taken as input locally from the image folder?
I'm working on a project that downloads the Cifar10 dataset, then applies poisoning to the cifar10 images, a change to the images at the bottom right. At this point, however, I no longer want to use the cifar10 images, but I want to be able to use my local images, so I took the images locally as input with ImageFolder.
Apparently the output of the CIFAR10 dataset and the output of the ImageFolder function have different formats and when I go to the add_trigger_dirty_label function the result of ImageFolder() gives me errors, this is what I tried:
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

NORMALIZATION_PARAMS = [[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]]
INPUT_SIZE = 224
PATH = './DB'


def generate_trigger(trigger_type):
    if trigger_type == 'checkerboard_1corner':  # checkerboard at the right bottom corner
        pattern = np.zeros(shape=(32, 32, 1), dtype=np.uint8) + 122
        mask = np.zeros(shape=(32, 32, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
        trigger_value = [[0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 255]]
        trigger_region = [-1, 0, 1]
        for h in trigger_region:
            for w in trigger_region:
                pattern[30 + h, 30 + w, 0] = trigger_value[h + 1][w + 1]
                mask[30 + h, 30 + w, 0] = 1
    return pattern, mask


def add_trigger_dirty_label(data_set, trigger_type, poison_rate, poison_target, trigger_alpha=1.0):
    pattern, mask = generate_trigger(trigger_type=trigger_type)
    poison_cand = [i for i in range(len(data_set.targets)) if data_set.targets[i] != poison_target]
    poison_set = deepcopy(data_set)
    poison_num = int(poison_rate * len(poison_cand))
    choices = np.random.choice(poison_cand, poison_num, replace=False)

    for idx in choices:
        orig = poison_set.data[idx]
        poison_set.data[idx] = np.clip(
            (1 - mask) * orig + mask * ((1 - trigger_alpha) * orig + trigger_alpha * pattern), 0, 255
        ).astype(np.uint8)
        poison_set.targets[idx] = poison_target
    trigger_info = {'trigger_pattern': pattern[np.newaxis, :, :, :], 'trigger_mask': mask[np.newaxis, :, :, :],
                    'trigger_alpha': trigger_alpha, 'poison_target': np.array([poison_target]),
                    'data_index': choices}
    return poison_set, trigger_info


def add_trigger_clean_label(data_set, trigger_type, poison_rate, poison_target, trigger_alpha=1.0):
    pattern, mask = generate_trigger(trigger_type=trigger_type)
    poison_cand = [i for i in range(len(data_set.targets)) if data_set.targets[i] == poison_target]
    poison_set = deepcopy(data_set)
    poison_num = int(poison_rate * len(poison_cand))
    choices = np.random.choice(poison_cand, poison_num, replace=False)

    for idx in choices:
        orig = poison_set.data[idx]
        poison_set.data[idx] = np.clip(
            (1 - mask) * orig + mask * ((1 - trigger_alpha) * orig + trigger_alpha * pattern), 0, 255
        ).astype(np.uint8)
    trigger_info = {'trigger_pattern': pattern[np.newaxis, :, :, :], 'trigger_mask': mask[np.newaxis, :, :, :],
                    'trigger_alpha': trigger_alpha, 'poison_target': np.array([poison_target]),
                    'data_index': choices}
    return poison_set, trigger_info


def add_predefined_trigger(data_set, trigger_info):
    if trigger_info is None:
        return data_set

    poison_set = deepcopy(data_set)

    pattern = trigger_info['trigger_pattern']
    mask = trigger_info['trigger_mask']
    alpha = trigger_info['trigger_alpha']

    for idx in range(len(poison_set)):
        orig = poison_set.data[idx]
        poison_set.data[idx] = np.clip(
            (1 - mask) * orig + mask * ((1 - alpha) * orig + alpha * pattern), 0, 255
        ).astype(np.uint8)

    return poison_set

from torchvision import datasets, transforms


data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(INPUT_SIZE),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(NORMALIZATION_PARAMS[0], NORMALIZATION_PARAMS[1])
])

image_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=PATH, transform=data_transforms)
#image_dataset = CIFAR10(root='./', train=True, download=True, transform=data_transforms)

poison_rate = 0.1
poison_target = 1

poisoned_dataset, trigger_info = add_trigger_dirty_label(image_dataset, 'checkerboard_1corner', poison_rate, poison_target)

This is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\enric\PycharmProjects\Avvelenatore\main.py", line 92, in <module>
    poisoned_dataset, trigger_info = add_trigger_dirty_label(image_dataset, 'checkerboard_1corner', poison_rate, poison_target)
  File "C:\Users\enric\PycharmProjects\Avvelenatore\main.py", line 30, in add_trigger_dirty_label
    orig = poison_set.data[idx]
  File "C:\Users\enric\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError

How to make this change, i.e. use the data locally with ImageFolder, and then pass it to the add_trigger_dirty_label() function?
